# RecyclerView get hidden under dynamic view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in an xml and a `LinearLayout` at the bottom of that Activity. This activity works as a chat window where a question appears as the chat message and user gets some random multiple choice options in the view, but when the `RecyclerView` gets populated with a page full of data, I want to make that `RecyclerView` always above the layout where options are created, but what I have done so far does not work as expected, the `RecyclerView` data always gets hidden under the layout and each time I need to scroll down to see what's written there. I have used the method

```
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(array.size());
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(array.size());
```

This adds item in the `RecyclerView`and also scrolls down but it gets hidden  under the layout, but I have set it always above the layout in the xml, I think the problem is I am creating some views dynamically in that layout which's size is wrap content, so the `RecyclerView` is not being updated time to time with the height of the layout in the bottom. Here is the xml code of that Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatBotActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header"></include>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/fade" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="sendClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:text="send" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The `RecyclerView` is always above of the `LinearLayout` which id is `ll` but I am populating that layout from the java and it's height changes time to time, but `RecyclerView` height doesn't changed accordingly, please help!

Comment: could you provide some screen shots?

Comment: As you have given wrap_content to ll layout, so the layout is increasing its height as per the content. You have to fix the layout height.

Comment: @Ankit Is'nt there any chance to resize the recyclerview height and refresh the layout?

Comment: That will be quite weird if you are shrinking the RV according to LL content. I would suggest you can use scroll layout for LL. Or you can define % height ratios. But that won't be a perfect solution as in few cases that can look very weird.
I would say you can prefer bootomsheet popup for Layout view like google maps or try other alternative designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I myself solved the question, It was a funny mistake I was doing, the layout was all right, but my recylerview was just not scrolling, I had to change this:

Previous:

```
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(array.size());
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(array.size());
```

Later:

```
adapter.notifyItemInserted(array.size()-1);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(array.size()-1);
```